# Is there a regex to exclude a word list in awk?

Tags: regex, awk, regex-negation

In an awk program , I'm trying to select the input from a line containing `<<<local>>>` and the next line containing the pattern `<<<XXXX>>>`, where
`XXXX` will be anything else but `local`.

```
<<<local>>>
line1
line2
line3
<<<XXXX>>>
```

The simplest awk code would be

```
$0=="<<<local>>>",/^<<<XXXX>>>$/ { ··· }
```

but `XXXX` should be replaced with a proper regular expression to exclude `local`.

As far I know, that can be done in python

```
(?!local)
```

and in Korn shell and other shells:

```
!(local)
```

but I have found nothing about this issue in the regex(7) man pages.

In order to bypass this handicap I use

```
$0=="<<<local>>>",/^<<<.+>>>$/ && $0!="<<<local>>>" { ··· }
```

but the crux of this question of mine is wether the `awk` regex engine accepts somehow a word list to exclude, I mean, as a counterpart of `word1|word2|word3`.

Comment: While the information is helpful. Can you give an actual example input and an expected output needed to help us understand bette

Comment: Even `line1` will also satisfy negative lookahead that is `(?!local)`

Comment: example of input/output please

Comment: awk doesn't support lookarounds.. and I'd suggest to use flags(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-select-lines-between-two-patterns/) instead of `//,//` syntax...

Comment: @Inian@Allan  I do not want you to provide me an awk code. Actually I want you to answer what I asked in the two last lines of my question.

Comment: It sure does provide. You can do `!/word1/ && !/word2/ && !/word3/`

Answer (score 0):

this would do...

```
awk '/<<<local>>>/{f=1} f; /<<<.*>>>/ && !/<<<local>>>/{f=0}' file
```

if you don't want to terminate the range for another word you can add to `!/<<<(local|other)>>>/`